# Unable to install TestNG plugin in latest Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

I am getting below error when trying install TestNG in latest Eclipse:

[image]

Could anyone help out in resolving this issue as my project uses TestNG in the Test framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps and anybody can get the testNG working in any version of Eclipse:

1. Download the source code from the github : [testNG Source in Git](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/blob/master/README.md#building) and take any version that suits your needs

[image: TestNG official Git Source]

2. Once downloaded extract the folder to eclipse directory: Let's assume hypothetically you have kept it in **C:** drive, then the path where you would extract is: **C:\eclipse\dropins** : Preferably use **7zip** extracter to unzip it to directory
   [image: Downloaded TestNG source zip]
3. Extract and place the folder in **dropins** folder of eclipse [image: Extracted TestNG folder in dropin folder][image: Internal of extracted folder, just for reference]
4. Once extracted, you need to add one file to the folder: **site.xml**. Create a site.xml file and add the below details: and where ever **<TestNG_Version_downloaded>** is quoted, please don't forget to add the testNG version downloaded

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <site>
   <feature url="features/org.testng.eclipse_<TestNG_Version_downloaded>.jar" id="org.testng.eclipse" version="<TestNG_Version_downloaded>">
      <category name="org.testng.eclipse"/>
   </feature>
   <feature url="features/org.testng.eclipse.maven.feature_7.0.0.201908240652.jar" id="org.testng.eclipse.maven.feature" version="<TestNG_Version>">
      <category name="org.testng.eclipse"/>
   </feature>
   <category-def name="org.testng.eclipse" label="TestNG"/>
   ```

and the xml file content just for reference: [image: XML file view in browser(For reference)]

5. Once Everything is done: Go to Eclipse, and perform **ctrl+N** and you can see testNG appearing in the menu and that's it and you are ready to use TestNG. Happy Coding!![image: TestNG in Eclipse][image: TestNG in Eclipse]